# CSS background color and png image

Tags: css

It probably requires a workaround, or extra elements to achieve, but I'll ask anyway.

I have a simple image. The image is split into two diagonally. The top is a solid color and the bottom is transparent. If I apply the following code, the background color fills in the transparency of the image. Is there a way to position the color or not have it show through where my image area is and instead just fill the remainder of the element?

```
#content:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: -35px;
    content: "";
    width: 35px;
    height: 465px;
    left: -35px;
    background: #121314 url(library/images/content-fold-left.png) 0 bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That will be a bit tough - using just the `background` property you won't be able to control where the background color starts versus where to position the background image. You may have to use one or more separate child elements rather than a pseudo-element. Or perhaps you could try using `:before` and `:after`; one for the image and one for the background color, but either way you have to worry about positioning each one.

Comment: That's what I figured, but never hurts to ask! Thanks for your input.

Comment: @BoltClock I think this would be a good place for a CSS3 gradient. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS3 Gradients:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100, color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #fa8072));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #fa8072 100px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #fa8072 100px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #fa8072 100px);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #fa8072 100px);
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/zfidk).

You'll notice I used Sass and Compass. The different gradient syntaxes are a nightmare, but with Sass and Compass, all you have to write is:

```
body
  +background(linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100px, salmon 100px))
```

And it will  compile all the vendor prefixes and different legacy syntaxes for you.

Comment: Pretty sweet, I'm gonna check this out...how will it interact with IE 8 & 9?